# What is a by statement really doing in a sas data step?

Tags: duplicates, sas, datastep

Okay this seems like a very simple thing, but I can't explain what a "by statement" in a sas datastep is really doing.  I know when I need to use it, but I am not sure what it is doing.

In the example below I understand what the virtual sas column of first.var and last.var is when it has the values that it does.  Is the by statement creating these virtual columns around the var initial and metal?  Then sas is scanning the entire data set once?

```
data jewelers ;
  input id initial $ metal $ ;
datalines;
456 D Gold
456 D Silver
123 L Gold
123 L Copper
123 L PLatinum
567 R Gold
567 R Gold
567 R Gold
345 A Platinum
345 A Silver
345 A Silver
;

proc sort ;
  by initial metal ;
run;

data dups;
  set jewelers ;
  by initial metal ;                           
  if not (first.metal and last.metal) then output;
run;
```

if I proc print dups I expect this:

```
567 R Gold
567 R Gold
567 R Gold
345 A Silver
345 A Silver
```

Comment: in your example `first.id` and `last.id` are uninitialised as they do not appear in the `by` statement. To see which hidden variables are created, add a `put _all_;` statement after your `by` statement. (Only do this for small datasets as it has the potential to fill the log).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've acknowledged, SAS is creating the automatic variables `first.byvar` and `last.byvar` for each `byvar` in your `by` statement. Records read in from a `set` statement are held in a buffer before SAS moves them to the PDV (Program Data Vector - where data step logic is executed on each row before it is output), so SAS can look ahead to the next record in the buffer to see whether any of the byvars have changed, and set `last.byvar = 1` for the row currently in the PDV.

The only difference I can see between what you say you expect and what you get in the dups dataset is the order of the records - because you've sorted by initial and then metal, the `A Silver` records are sorted ahead of the `R Gold` records.

If you want to get duplicates across these two variables while preserving the original row order, you'd need to make a note of what the original record order was and sort your duplicates dataset back into that order after your second data step.

Answer (score 0):

SAS is basically comparing the current record to the one before and the one after to calculate the FIRST. and LAST. flags.  You can roll your own if you want.

```
data test ;
   set jewelers end=eof;
   by initial metal ;
   if not eof then 
      set jewelers (firstobs=2 keep=initial metal 
                    rename=(initial=next_initial metal=next_metal))
   ;
   first_initial = (_n_=1) or (initial ne lag(initial));
   last_initial = eof or (initial ne next_initial) ;
   first_metal = first_initial or (metal ne lag(metal)) ;
   last_metal = last_initial or (metal ne next_metal);
   put / (initial metal) (=);
   put (first:) (=);
   put (last:) (=);
run;
```